# How to shutdown service before systemd starts unmounting

Tags: systemd, filesystems, unmounting, systemd-mount

I have a systemd service that uses `After=local-fs.target` to ensure that all mount points are established (if possible) before the service is started.

Not being too familiar with the systemd infrastructure, I assumed that the service will be stopped before the mounts are unmounted during shutdown.
To my surprise this does not seem to be the case though.

I could see multiple times that my service failed to write its configuration (done during shutdown) because the location that's being used for it was already unmounted.

After some research I think I have narrowed it down to the unit type of `local-fs.target` which seems to not be considered in the shutdown order - I might be wrong though.
There was no definitive answer to my question yet.

How can I make sure that my service is stopped before the mount points are unmounted during shutdown phase?

Comment: I'm taking a guess here: though I haven't had a similar problem, is it possibly that you only specified `After=local-fs.target`, but not a `Requires=local-fs.target`?

Comment: (`After` only specifies the *order* of starting, should two units be started together, `Requires` actually defines the dependency)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I will check if this is the case and try to change it if not. Thanks for the input.